# How to enable SSO when using private mode in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, authentication

In Firefox, I can enable SSO (Single sign-on) or Integrated Authentication using these two options:

```
network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris

network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris
```

It works as expected. But does not work in **Private mode.**

Can someone tell me how to enable this is Private mode also?

Answer (score 2):

This is by design.

For example, see the bug-report from 5 years ago :
[Firefox uses SSO Windows Integrated Authentication in Private Browsing Mode](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=914227).

Integrated Authentication working in Private mode was here reported as a bug.
It was marked resolved 2 years ago, meaning that this loophole has now been closed.

You might still try the two settings in the bug-report,
`network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris` and `network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris`,
in the hope that the bug has returned, but remember that you are looking
for an unintended way of using Firefox.

Comment: So we can not enable SSO in Private mode? I tried those settings but they only work in normal mode.

Comment: @That is the logical conclusion and I agree, it's by design and makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can enable the SSO in Firefox private mode by setting "network.auth.private-browsing-sso" to true (along with the regular settings you do  in normal mode).